# Why does Windows 7 remove Authenticated Users from file permissions when a folder is shared?

Tags: windows, windows-permissions

When I try to share a folder using the share tab in file properties, if I go back and remove sharing options from the Share tab, it also affects the Security tab, removing inheritance of permissions from the parent and also removing the Authenticated Users permission, causing the little lock icon on the folder to appear.

So I think I partially understand it, but at the same time, not really. I get that sharing a folder changes sharing permissions, but I'm not entirely sure why it is changing local permissions. I'm not smart enough to figure this out on my own, sorry.

Comment: Did you use the "Advanced Sharing" button which lets you choose the settings or the "Sharing" button which basically sets everything up for you? In the latter case, permissions will be changed to satisfy the users you choose to share the folder with in the dialogue.

Comment: The more simple sharing button.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Share... button Windows will push the share rights on to the file permissions. Period!

Use Advanced Sharing... button if you want to separate the share permissions from the file permissions.

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Stack Exchange! I took the liberty of removing the rant; rants attract downvotes. If you disagree with the edit, you can roll it back. To roll it back, click on the "edited ... ago". This takes you to the edit history, where you have the rollback options.